# Errors whilst trying to add data to a local databse

Tags: c#, database, t-sql, visual-studio-2017

Currently I am using Visual Studio with C# and TSQL to help create a school register/timeInOut system.
I have created a registration form in windows forms in which should add user data to a database, however I receive the two errors:

> Suppression StateError    The target database schema could not be
>   retrieved. Unable to reconnect to database: Cannot open database
>   "G:\NEA\GARDENREGISTER\GARDENREGISTER\GARDENREGISTER.MDF" requested by
>   the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'Tom\Tom
>   Slater'.      G:\NEA\GARDENREGISTER\GARDENREGISTER\GARDENREGISTER.MDF 0
>   Error     Failed to obtain schema information from database
>   (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.G:\NEA\GARDENREGISTER\GARDENREGISTER\GARDENREGISTER.MDF.
>   Please close any open editors for this database, check your connection
>   to this database, and refresh the database in Server
>   Explorer.     G:\NEA\GARDENREGISTER\GARDENREGISTER\GARDENREGISTER.MDF 0

Connectionstring:

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GardenRegister.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

I cannot make any sense of this other than the program is struggling to find my database, any help?
Below is the code for the register page

```
using (SqlConnection SQLCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    SQLCon.Open();
    SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserAdd", SQLCon)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Txt_NameReg.Text.Trim());
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Organisation", Txt_OrgReg.Text.Trim());
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DT_DobReg.Text);
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", Txt_RegCont.Text.Trim());
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address",Txt_RegAddress.Text.Trim());
    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Registration Successfull");
    Clear();
    SQLCon.Close();
```

Below is the useradd procedure:

```
CREATE PROC UserAdd
@Name VARCHAR(30),
@Organisation VARCHAR(20),
@DOB DATETIME,
@Contact VARCHAR(50),
@Address VARCHAR(250)
AS
INSERT INTO Member(Name, Organisation,DOB,Contact,Address)
VALUES (@Name,@Organisation,@DOB,@Contact,@Address)
```

Comment: How does the connection string look like?

Comment: You are not able to connect to DataBase. Re look at your connection string.

Comment: @UweKeim Ive added it above,
in case you cannot see the edit it is: 
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GardenRegister.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

Comment: You wouldn't get a login failed message if the database could not be found.